# Download an asset file from code artifact

Tags: aws-sdk-js, aws-codeartifact

### Problem Statement-

I am writing a simple program that downloads a `JAR file` from AWS `code-artifact` to a designated path (on my local system).

I am using code `artifact client` from JavaScript SDK v3. Here is the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-codeartifact/classes/getpackageversionassetcommand.html) to the package.

### Approach-

Followed the documentation and this is what the code looks like-

```
const { CodeartifactClient, GetPackageVersionAssetCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-codeartifact");

const input = {
    asset : "",
    domain : "",
    domainOwner : "",
    format : "",
    namespace : "",
    package : "",
    packageVersion : "",
    repository : ""
}

const command = new GetPackageVersionAssetCommand(input);

async function getPackageAsset(command){
    const response = await client.send(command);
    
    console.log(response);
}
getPackageAsset(command);
```

The code returns the `$metadata` field as it is supposed to. However, it does not really download the file; which is understandable because **I never provided a path** to download the file.

That brings me to the question- **How do I provide the API with a path so that it can download the JAR file ?**

I checked the `awscli` documentation and this is how it does and here is the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/download-assets.html) to the documentation -

[Image of awscli documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR97C.png)

But, I am not sure how to provide that local storage path in the JS code.

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: I did this using python SDK, in my case it will download all artifacts, maybe this can be userfull to you as a reference. Basically, seeing the code you can get the logical of how to download an asset from aws codeartifact and apply it in JavaScript. https://github.com/wilkersena/aws-codeartifact-utility